# Qt: 'Expected Primary Expression Before ')' Token when Changing Property?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm using Qt with C++ using Qt Creator. I have a `QGraphicsView` in my window named `render` and I wish to set its scene programatically. In window.cpp:

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
ui->render->scene(scene*);
```

I have included `QtGui` and `QGraphicsView`.

When I attempt to compile the program I get:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Does anybody have any advice with regards to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsView::scene()` returns the scene, use `setScene(QGraphicsScene* scene)` to set it.  You are also adding an asterisk after `scene`, which when used *after* an object usually means to multiply it - that's why it's expecting another something before ')'.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked! Do you recommend removing the asterisk after QGraphicsScene?

Comment: I suggest you read a book on C++ basics, it'll save you a lot of trial and error.  And `QGraphicsScene*` is a pointer to a `QGraphicsScene`, which is the return type of a `new QGraphicsScene()` operation - so you need it.